# Powershell help for deleting files of certain age, but also using wildcards within script

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell, but have been successful putting together from various searches, the way to remove files of a certain age, within a specific folder.

My issue is that now within that specific folder, I now need to only remove certain file names, and not ALL files older than a specific date.

The script I am currently using is:

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-14)
$path = "C:\Folder\Files-in-specific-folder"

# Delete files older than the $limit.
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Force
```

This works great to just delete files older that 14 days, but how do I add say a wildcard that it uses to ONLY delete files with the name web in it?

Thanks much!
Mike

Comment: [`Get-Help Get-ChildItem -Full`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6) will provide a lot of useful information on how `Get-ChildItem` works. I commend to your attention `-Filter`, `-Include`, `-Exclude`, and the detailed information on `-Path`.

Answer (score 0):

When entering a script block for where-object, or any function that will process a script block. You can have multiple instances as long as you clearly seperate them.

For example:

```
Get-Command | Where-Object {($_.Name -like '*clear*') -and ($_.CommandType -eq 'cmdlet')}
```

So for your script just apply the same concept and add a name Filter to your existing Filter:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { ($_.Name -like "*web*") -and (!$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit) } | Remove-Item -Force
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll give it a try!